# Spring MVC Illegal state exception will initializing web application context

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat

I am trying to integrate PostgreSQL database with Spring MVC project. While executing the project on tomcat I faced the following exceptions and information:

```
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.47
Jan 27, 2018 5:37:40 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
17:37:40,179 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback.groovy]
17:37:40,179 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback-test.xml]
17:37:40,180 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Found resource [logback.xml] at [file:/home/robin/BE/SEM8/cl3/A3/bmfinal/target/classes/logback.xml]

Jan 27, 2018 5:37:40 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
2018-01-27 17:37:40 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR o.s.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 14 in XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 14; columnNumber: 75; cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans'.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:399) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
```

Following is pom.xml file

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mkyong</groupId>
    <artifactId>bmfinal</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>booths multiplication Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <jdk.version>1.7</jdk.version>
        <spring.version>4.1.7.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <jstl.version>1.2</jstl.version>
        <junit.version>4.11</junit.version>
        <logback.version>1.0.13</logback.version>
        <jcl-over-slf4j.version>1.7.5</jcl-over-slf4j.version>

        <hibernate.version>4.3.5.Final</hibernate.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- Unit Test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2-beta</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.7.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
        <!-- Spring Core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${jcl-over-slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>${logback.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- jstl -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>${jstl.version}</version>
        </dependency>

         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.4.1207.jre7</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
    <!-- Spring ORM -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>BoothsMultiplication</finalName>

        <plugins>
            <!-- Eclipse project -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- Always download and attach dependencies source code -->
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <downloadJavadocs>false</downloadJavadocs>
                    <!-- mvn eclipse:eclipse -Dwtpversion=2.0 -->
                    <wtpversion>2.0</wtpversion>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!-- Set JDK Compiler Level -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${jdk.version}</source>
                    <target>${jdk.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!-- For Tomcat -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <path>/bmfinal</path>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>

    </build>
</project>
```

and mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml file

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" 
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation=
    "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-tx-4.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.mkyong.controller" />
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>


    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
        <property name="url"
            value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/ucan" />
        <property name="username" value="ucan" />
        <property name="password" value="ucan" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>com.mkyong.controller.Numbers</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
                </prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="nodao" class="com.mkyong.controller.NumberDAO">
        <property name="s" ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory" />
    </bean>


    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="s" ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is  because you have mvc as your root namespace (`xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"`) instead of beans, which you have declared in the `beans` namespace.

Try replacing the top part of your mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml with the following to declare beans as your root namespace.

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xsi:schemaLocation= "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-tx-4.0.xsd">
```

Alternatively, you could qualify all references to items in the beans namespace. So `<beans>` becomes `<beans:beans>` and `<bean>` becomes `<beans:bean>` etc.